# How to line up the bottom of side-by-side Div layers in CSS

Tags: css

So I am working on a site, I have 4 DIV boxes left to right. How do I get the backgrounds to line up along the bottom? The original site which was in the internet wayback machine has them laid out that way, but I am using a different theme.

Heres what I have written:

```
#smallbox {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 23%;
background-color: #1B5492;
margin: 1%;
bottom: 0;
}
#smallbox img {
padding: 0;
margin: -23px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#smallbox h3 {
color: #0CCEBE;
}
#smallbox p {
color: #ffffff;
min-height: 200px;
```

And an example of this in context is: `

```
<img src="" alt="UNLIMITED PROFITS" />
<h3>How Much Can I Make?</h3>
The average work day for doing surveys is about 2 hours, and the average income per month is $4500. Do the math: 2 hours a day x 30 days a month = 60 hours a month. $4500/60 hours = $75/hour. How many 9 to 5 boring office jobs pay that?

</div>
```

The site is surveysoup.com. I tried a few things on here, like bottom:0;, but that didnt help

Comment: the question does not show research effort.

Comment: Do you want their background to stretch to the bottom, or to align all bottom corners on the same line?
You should add some css to your question!

Comment: Can you try `#smallbox p {min-height: 200px;}`

Comment: @MarianRick, I want the background to stretch to the bottom. Thanks for the notes, Ill add what I tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is Equal Column height issue. There are a lot of guides on solving it:

- [Quick Tip: Solving the Equal Height Column Conundrum](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403)
- [CSS Equal Height Columns, Three Different Ways](http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

A quick and dirty fix is to use a fixed height, which can be done by giving this in your CSS:

```css
#smallbox p {min-height: 200px;}
```

Another fix is to use `tabular design`. As we are **not** supposed to use `table`s for layout purposes, some people still use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for `<div>`s and others. You can try the following:

```css
#smallbox {display: table;}
#smallbox p {display: table-cell; height: 100%;}
```

Another fix is to use [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which is supported only by modern browsers. This gives it a table style design.

```css
#smallbox {display: flex;}
#smallbox p {flex: 1;}
```

**Note:** And more important thing is, it looks like you are reusing the same IDs. You must not do that. Change `#smallbox` to `.smallbox`, so that it looks better for all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known as [equal height columns](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/)

```css
.row{
    display: flex;
}

.cols{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cols">...</div>
    <div class="cols">...</div>
    <div class="cols">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your divs `#smallbox` do not change their size or height, you could use a simple fix:

```
min-height: 580px;
```

If they are going to change, you could nest them inside a container div:

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="smallbox">Content</div>
 <div class="smallbox">Content</div>
 <div class="smallbox">Content</div>
 <div class="smallbox">Content</div>
</div>
```

Set the containers height as so `min-height: 570px`, and assign the `height: 100%` to your `#smallbox`.

Be aware of the difference between `classes` and `ids`. The last should always be used only once per html page! [**Read about class vs id**](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Im new to CSS work. Any particular reason to use classes versus ID?

Comment: I have added a quick to my answer. To make it short: Repeating styles are added using classes, while unique styles are added to an id. Each id should only be used once per page!